# What’s the quickest, easiest way to execute a JavaScript file on a live web page?

Tags: javascript, console, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

I have this JavaScript file URL:

https://rawgit.com/Khan/tota11y/master/build/tota11y.min.js

(hosted on GitHub and passed through RawGit), and I would like to inject it into a live web page via the browser’s console.

In order to achieve that, I can dynamically create a `<script>` element and append it to the DOM:

```
(function () {
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.src = 'https://rawgit.com/Khan/tota11y/master/build/tota11y.min.js';
  document.body.appendChild(s);
}())
```

But this is neither quick nor easy. I would like to use an API that makes this possible via a simple invocation, e.g.:

```
exec('https://rawgit.com/Khan/tota11y/master/build/tota11y.min.js')
```

Do Chrome or Firefox provide such an API (or anything similar) in their console?

---

**Use case:** Quickly testing JavaScript libraries hosted on GitHub on live web pages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update: [The Developer Toolbar has been removed from Firefox Nightly as of 18th May 2018.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/GCLI)

In Firefox, you can inject scripts using the Developer Toolbar. Bring it up with`Shift+F2` and type `inject https://rawgit.com/Khan/tota11y/master/build/tota11y.min.js`

[More info on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/GCLI)

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: We [have plans](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=789675) to fold the command system from the developer toolbar into the console itself, hopefully later this year.

Answer (score 0):

You need a module loading capability from what I see. You have two routes:

- Either use a module loader like [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/) that already does that kind of dynamic loading for you. It enforces you to use AMD style of scripts though. [This website](http://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/) talks a bit more about modules in javascript. The `require` object will be available in console since it is global.
- Use a hackish function that does that like [jQuery does here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/), if you use jQuery already (it is a pretty big library to import just for this). jQuery is global and you can call that function in console.

**EDIT**: The reason I did not link browser specific functionality is because it is too specific. Using a JavaScript only solution works across all browsers to test for compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

For chrome there's a plugin called Script Injector that does exactly that

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/script-injector/fddnddnolonllcgfbenaloajnbhebmob?hl=en